# 2D - How to create nation`s territory from set of coordinates

Tags: c#

I want to create nation`s "sphere of influence" from systems they own on a map.
Map is just a 2D grid of Vector2 coordinates.

**The territory/shape can and will also be concave!**

This is how it looks now:

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

**So basically, input arguments are set of Vector2D points, output would be set of all Vector2D points that would create this sphere of influence.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convex hull library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671206/convex-hull-library)

Comment: So you search for a way turn points to a convex polygon?

Comment: @Progman ... except that this is concave...

Comment: @Wryman Finding a concave hull is not as straightforward, as with the convex hull, as there are more theoretical solutions (see: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1309/1309.7829.pdf). Unfortunately "influence" isn't well defined mathematically. What I would try, is to start from the convex hull. The, defining a direction of traversal, for each edge, find the nearest internal points to that edge (not to the line, only to the edge). Bind them in the same direction and replace the original edge with these new edges.